# How do you split at the end of the line in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, split, delimiter

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
Event=ThermostatNight,time=0
Event=LightOn,time=2000
Event=WaterOff,time=10000
Event=ThermostatDay,time=12000
Event=Bell,time=9000,rings=5
Event=WaterOn,time=6000
Event=LightOff,time=4000
Event=Terminate,time=20000
Event=FansOn,time=7000
Event=FansOff,time=8000
```

I'm trying to store the above into an array, for example the array should be:

```
[0] = Event
[1] = ThermostatNight
[2] = time
[3] = 0
[4] = Event
[5] = LightOn
[6] = time
[7] = 2000
//.... etc
```

Basically I'm trying to store the event name as a variable and the time as another variable and using = and , as split points. However, at index [3] shows "0Event" and index [6] shows "2000Event", etc.

I'm not sure if I should be using a new line as a split point or white space, or I might just be looking at this the wrong way. Here is my code:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
try {
    
Scanner content = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter(",");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
while(content.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(content.nextLine());
        }

String[] wordsArray = sb.toString().split("[=,]");

//Test what is at each index
System.out.println(wordsArray[3]);          
}
    
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

I've been playing around with String[] wordsArray = sb.toString().split("[=,]"); and have tried modifying the code to:

```
.split("\[=,\\n\]")
.split("\[=,\\s\]")
.split("\[=,\\n\]")
...etc
```

and many other different arguments inside of .split.

But I still keep getting index [3] and [6] as 0Event and 2000Event.

Again not sure if I might just be looking at this the wrong way or taking the wrong approach. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you read the `content.nextLine()` the linebreak character is being stripped off. so your StringBuilder, does not have a linebreak character to use for `String.split`. Append it to your StringBuilder on each line and then you can use the pattern `\\R` in your `split` operation like `.split("\[=,\\R]")` (See linebreak matcher at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Running your program under the debugger would have allowed you to see that there was no newline character where you expected one to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... I'm trying to store the above into an array ..."*

> *"... I'm not sure if I should be using a new line as a split point or white space, or I might just be looking at this the wrong way ..."*

There are several ways to accomplish this task.

You can add more values to the *[Scanner#useDelimiter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String))* call, and then use *[next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next())*, instead of *[nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())*.

```
\r\n?|\n|[,=]
```

This will allow you to get rid of the *StringBuilder*.
And for the *wordsArray*, use a *[List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)* initially, and convert to an array when needed.

```java
try {

Scanner content = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\r\n?|\n|[,=]");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

while(content.hasNext()) {
    list.add(content.next());
        }

String[] wordsArray = list.toArray(new String[0]);

//Test what is at each index
System.out.println(wordsArray[3]);
}

catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or, use the *Scanner* as is, without a modified delimiter, and use the *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))* method.

```java
while(content.hasNextLine())
    wordsArray.addAll(List.of(content.nextLine().split("[,=]")));
```

```java
try {

Scanner content = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

while(content.hasNext()) {
    list.addAll(List.of(content.nextLine().split("[,=]")));
        }

String[] wordsArray = list.toArray(new String[0]);

//Test what is at each index
System.out.println(wordsArray[3]);
}

catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output

```
0
```

> *"... Again not sure if I might just be looking at this the wrong way or taking the wrong approach. Any help is greatly appreciated."*

Instead of *Scanner*, you can use the *[BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html)* class, which offers the *[lines](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines())* method.

```java
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {
    List<String> list = reader.lines()
                              .flatMap(x -> Stream.of(x.split("[,=]")))
                                                  .toList();
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Getting rid of the StringBuilder helped, and adding the correct values to the delimiter did the trick. I tested the code and it's outputting properly now.

Comment: Note that there is a pattern for handling all kinds of line breaks, `\R`, eliminating the need to use something like `\r\n?|\n`. Further, `Scanner` supports the Stream API since Java 9, so you can simply use, e.g. `String[] array; try(Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")) .useDelimiter("\\R|[,=]")) { array = s.tokens().toArray(String[]::new); }` (a `Scanner` has to be closed the same way a `Reader` has to be closed)

Comment: @Holger, I heard there is some bug with `\R`, where it counts the `\r\n` incorrectly.  A `\R\R` will match a `\r\n`, which is incorrect; a single `\R` should match the entire sequence.  I haven't researched it much from there, so I wouldn't recommend it.  The _Scanner_ stream is nice, I don't use _Scanner_ much.  You should add it as an answer.

Comment: Well, `"\r\n".matches("\\R\\R")` evaluates to `true`, which is to be expected considering how `matches` work. The same happens with your pattern, i.e. `"\r\n".matches("(\r\n?|\n){2}")` also evaluates to `true`. But this does not affect the way, `split` works. In other words, both, `"X\r\nY".split("\\R")` and `"X\r\nY".split("\r\n?|\n")` correctly produce an array with two strings, `"X"`, `"Y"`, with no empty strings in-between.

Answer (score 3):

### tl;dr

I find splitting multiple times rather than regex to be simpler, clearer, and more self-documenting.

```java
input
        .lines ( )
        .flatMap ( line -> Arrays.stream ( line.split ( "," ) ) )
        .flatMap ( pair -> Arrays.stream ( pair.split ( "=" ) ) )
        .toArray ( String[] :: new );
```

### Split 3 times, nested

Why not triple nest calls to split?

In an outer loop, split on lines. Within that split on COMMA. Thirdly split on EQUALS SIGN.

```java
String input = """
        Event=ThermostatNight,time=0
        Event=LightOn,time=2000
        Event=WaterOff,time=10000
        Event=ThermostatDay,time=12000
        Event=Bell,time=9000,rings=5
        Event=WaterOn,time=6000
        Event=LightOff,time=4000
        Event=Terminate,time=20000
        Event=FansOn,time=7000
        Event=FansOff,time=8000
        """;
List < String > list = new ArrayList <> ( );
for ( String line : input.lines ( ).toList ( ) )
{
    for ( String pair : line.split ( "," ) )
    {
        for ( String keyOrValue : pair.split ( "=" ) )
        {
            list.add ( keyOrValue );
        }
    }
}
String[] array = list.toArray ( String[] :: new );
```

> array = [Event, ThermostatNight, time, 0, Event, LightOn, time, 2000, Event, WaterOff, time, 10000, Event, ThermostatDay, time, 12000, Event, Bell, time, 9000, rings, 5, Event, WaterOn, time, 6000, Event, LightOff, time, 4000, Event, Terminate, time, 20000, Event, FansOn, time, 7000, Event, FansOff, time, 8000]

---

Your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) might suggest replacing that inner loop with a call to `addAll`.

```java
for ( String line : input.lines ( ).toList ( ) )
{
    for ( String pair : line.split ( "," ) )
    {
        list.addAll ( Arrays.asList ( pair.split ( "=" ) ) );
    }
}
```

---

For even more compact code, we can use streams and `flatMap` to produce a one-liner.

```java
String[] array =
        input
                .lines ( )
                .flatMap ( line -> Arrays.stream ( line.split ( "," ) ) )
                .flatMap ( pair -> Arrays.stream ( pair.split ( "=" ) ) )
                .toArray ( String[] :: new );
```

Comment: Would be right thing if the OP accept this or provide feedback.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I need to have it work with my file rather than all of the content as a String. Scanner content = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter(",");

Comment: @Kyle its only an example. You should _reference_ the answer in order to write your own

Comment: @4K4K1N [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path)) works just like the `String#lines` shown here in the Answer. Both return a `Stream` of `String` objects.

Comment: There is no requirement to do three nested split operations, as the result is not different to a single split operation matching all three delimiters: `String[] array = input.split("\\R|[,=]");` The same logic can be applied to a `Scanner` as well, `String[] array = new Scanner(input) .useDelimiter("\\R|[,=]").tokens().toArray(String[]::new);`

Answer (score 1):

A someone mentioned above, you would be better off taking an OO approach to modelling your event. Note the anomalous record with the "rings" attribute. That would be another way of describing *repetitions*. It's a bell here, but could have been a buzzer or something else.
Once you've done that, you can parse the file into `Event` objects:

```
public class Event {
    private String name;
    private int duration;
    private int numRepetitions;

    public Event() {
    }

    public Event(String name, int duration, int numRepetitions) {
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.numRepetitions = numRepetitions;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return this.duration;
    }

    public int getNumRepetitions() {
        return this.numRepetitions;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public void setNumRepetitions(int numRepetitions) {
        this.numRepetitions = numRepetitions;
    }

    public static Event fromCsv(String[] tokens) {
        if (tokens.length == 4) {
            return new Event(tokens[1], Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]), 0);
        } else {
            return new Event(tokens[1], Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]), Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]));
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s=%s,%s=%d,%s=%d", "name", name, "duration", duration, "numRepetitions", numRepetitions);
    }
}
```

Parse the file:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;

public class EventParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Event> events = EventParser.parseEvents(Path.of(args[0]));
        events.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static List<Event> parseEvents(Path p) throws IOException {
        return Files.lines(p)
            .map(line ->line.split("[,=]"))
            .map(Event::fromCsv)
            .toList();
    }

}
```

Giving the output:

```
name=ThermostatNight,duration=0,numRepetitions=0
name=LightOn,duration=2000,numRepetitions=0
name=WaterOff,duration=10000,numRepetitions=0
name=ThermostatDay,duration=12000,numRepetitions=0
name=Bell,duration=9000,numRepetitions=5
name=WaterOn,duration=6000,numRepetitions=0
name=LightOff,duration=4000,numRepetitions=0
name=Terminate,duration=20000,numRepetitions=0
name=FansOn,duration=7000,numRepetitions=0
name=FansOff,duration=8000,numRepetitions=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should delimit your data one step at a time, and parse one line at a time rather than doing it all at once.

So in your case, each line (content.nextLine) should be split by a comma:

```
String attributes = line.split(',');
```

Then, take your *attributes* and split them individually to get your key and value:

```
for(String attribute : attributes) {
    String pairs = attribute.split('=');
    String key = attribute[0]; // Event, or time
    String value = attribute[1]; // LightsOn, or 2000

    // Do stuff with key and value, like add in your array
}
```

As a side note:

Unless you are required to add it to a primitive array, I would recommend making an object to represent the data you are parsing. That way you can just add a new object of that data (i.e. Event(String name, long time)) into an ArrayList of Events.